# How to apply changes to a single element in a Flatlist in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that renders multiple posts, each post has a text section, the text can get very big so I'm using a show more method to expand/hide the text, and I'm handling the status of it using a state, however, when I click on a post to expand the text, it expands all posts in the Flatlist, I tried creating a dynamic Ref for each post, but I can't figure out a way to change the text content accordingly, anything I'm missing?

here's my code:

```js
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  const refs = useRef([]);




// Inside a Flatlist render item: 

    <View style={styles.postContainer}>
      {item.data.postText.length > 120 ? (
        showMore ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}
           ref={(expandableText) => (refs.current[index] = expandableText)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{item.data.postText}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show less</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>
              {`${item.data.postText.slice(0, 120)}... `}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show more</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{item.data.postText}</Text>
      )}
    </View>
```

Comment: is the `<View ...>` being rendered within some sort of a looping construct (like `.map()`)? May be like: `items.map(item => { <View .....> ..... </View>});`

Comment: @jsN00b yes, in the Flatlist default renderItem={} method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same state for all items of the `FlatList`. Hence, if you change the state, all items will be expanded. You could keep a boolean array as a state. The index of this state array corresponds to the index of a component inside the flatlist.

```js
// data is the data of your FlatList
// we use this to initialize each show more value with false
const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(data.map(data => false))
```

In your render function you use it as follows.

```js
renderItem={({item, index}) => {
 return <View style={styles.postContainer}>
      {item.data.postText.length > 120 ? (
        showMore[index] ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleShowMore(index)}
           ref={(expandableText) => (refs.current[index] = expandableText)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{item.data.postText}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show less</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleShowMore(index)}>
            <Text style={styles.postDescription}>
              {`${item.data.postText.slice(0, 120)}... `}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.seeMore}>Show more</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.postDescription}>{item.data.postText}</Text>
      )}
    </View>
}
```

The `handleShowMore` function is as follows.

```js
function handleShowMore(index) {
    setShowMore(prev => prev.map((element, idx) => {
        if(idx === index) {
            return !element
        }
        return element
   }))
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much, only thing that i had to change was to put the showMore array in a useEffect because it was loading before the data, and returning 0 indexes.

Comment: If you can, would you please explain how the handleShowMore function is working, i want to understand this as much as possible

Comment: You are welcome. Great that it works for you. The `handleShowMore` function takes a single argument, the index of the item being rendered by the `FlatList` which we can access through the `renderItem` function. The setter function of a `state` allows to access the `current value of the state` which I have called `prev` (for previous). The value that is stored inside the state is an array. Hence `prev` is an array. The `map` function of an array returns again an array but allows to `map each item of the array to another value`. The `map` function passes the index (`idx`) for each item

Comment: (`element`) to the function that maps the values. If `idx` is equal to the `index` parameter that we have passed to `handleShowMore`, then we know that this is the item we have clicked on. Hence we return its opposite (`!element`). Otherwise we just return the original value. Thus if the state array would be `[false, false, false]` for three items and we clicked on the second item, then `index=1`. If the `map function` matches the index, it returns `!false` which is `true` and the original value otherwise which is `false`. The result of map is `[false, true, false]`.